# Удаление нечётных элементов из строки

Tags: python

Дана строка. Из нее нужно удалить все нечётные числа. При этом в строке также присутствует буквенная часть

Comment: Хотя-бы пример строки приведите

Answer (score 1):

```py
stroke = [i for i in input()]
stroke_2 = []
for i in stoke:
    if i.isdigit():
        if int(i) % 2 == 0:
            stroke_2.append(i)
print(''.join(stroke_2))
```

Comment: @Andrey аа да к инту не привел, код не тестил

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение

```
import re

a = 'строк567а с цифр334ами и буквам99870и 27'  # input()
print(re.sub(r'[13579]', '', a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно взять каждый элемент, попробовать привести его к числу, а далее проверить на нечётность и добавлять в массив, (если четный - добавляем, нечетный - пропускаем), всё остальное - добавляем. А там соединяем в строку

```py
a = input()

res = []
for i in a:
    try:
        num = int(i)
        if num % 2 == 0:
            res.append(i)
        else:
            continue
    except:
        res.append(i)

print(''.join(res))
```

Также пример:

Ввод: **ма23пл456а**
Вывод: **ма2пл46а**

*Как мы можем видеть всё работает*

Answer (score 0):

Предложу свой вариант:

```
print(''.join(_ for _ in input('Введите строку: ') if not _.isdigit() or int(_) % 2 == 0))
```